# Как сделать, чтобы программа отловила событие?

Tags: delphi

Пишу программу и не могу понять, как сделать вот это: надо, когда появляется окно, произвести некое действие. Все действия с окном я уже сделал, а вот поймать его не могу. Просто не знаю, как дописать условие: "если появилось окно, тогда...".

Comment: в отдельном потоке: FindWindow, с циклом и синхронизацией с основным потоком

Comment: можно пример кода или ссылку, что бы я пощупал, покрутил его ? мне порекомендовали копать в сторону SetWindowsHookEx

Comment: вообще не очень хорошо перехватывать события чужих приложений...
Но можно в цикле проверять, не появилось ли определенное окно...

Comment: Окно в вашей программе или чужой?

Answer (score 4):

В Delphi это можно сделать как минимум **двумя способами**:

- Описать сигнатуру
     функции-обработчика** системного
     сообщения в главном классе( в разделе
     public ):

  ```
   public
     procedure Catch(var msg:TMessage);message SW_SHOW;
   ...
  ```

И, соответственно, **реализация** уже такова, какой её реализуете вы. Предположим, мой пример, это:

```
    procedure TForm1.Catch(var msg: TMessage);
    begin
     showmessage('Caught!');
    end;
```

Таким методом можно обработать любое системное сообщение для любой формы приложения.

---

- Второй способ уже заключается в
     обработки сообщения уже средствами
     Delphi для каждой отдельной формы. Но, правда, так можно
     обработать далеко не каждое системное
     сообщение, поэтому решайте сами.
     Пример процедуры-обработчика:

  ```
     procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
     begin
      showmessage('Caught!');
     end;
  ```